# Is there a way to specify sensible alt-text for non-verbal text content?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

The tagline on my blog is “Just my $.02”. I tried this in Apple's VoiceOver screen reader, and the voice output was “Just my zero dollars and two cents.”

Is there anything like an `alt` attribute for `span` elements, where I could specify an alternative, verbal version of non-verbal text, like the following?

```
<p>Just my <span alt="two cents">$.02</span></p>
```

Comment: this might be a place to start:https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html

Comment: Thanks @AlexDurbin. It's definitely a step in the right direction, but not quite what I'm looking for. The screen reader (VoiceOver, at least) will read both the label and the content. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aria-hidden="true"` prevents a screen reader from announcing the text:

```
<p>
Just my <span aria-hidden="true">$.02</span><span class="visually-hidden">two cents</span>
</p>
```

The class `visually-hidden` hides the content from being visually displayed:

```
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding:0 !important;
  border:0 !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

These are combined to visually hide the text "two cents" but leave it in place for screen readers, while the text "$.02" is ignored by screen readers.